# name instead of number to send sms using AT commands

Tags: java, sms, gsm, at-command

Instead of the sender number to the recipient , i want it be name using the AT commands.

I am successfully send the message through AT commands using GSM Modem. Can somebody provide

the solution to send sms with sender name instead of the mobile number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually,
The sender can not send normal SMS message so that the receiver can read his name.
The receiving terminal can have capacity to search the number from phonebook and replace the number.
When the SMS is sent, then the number of the sender is not coded in to sending sms, because it is the feature of the network: 
When the MO SMS (SMS-Submit) is converted into MT- SMS (SMS-Deliver), then the number of the receiver 
"is replaced" with the number of the sender.
So you can not send the name instead of the number when you are using SMS.
      The network provider needs to be contacted in case a specific name/number needs to be displayed. AT commands would accept only the phone number as the CMGS parameter.
Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know, it's impossible to change to sender id when using a GSM modem. please see [this article](http://www.nowsms.com/discus/messages/1/9398.html) for details, especially the last part. you will need a connection to an SMSC (directly or indirectly) instead of using a GSM modem to get this to work.